# What is the purpose of "()=>"

Tags: c#

I haven't really come across this syntax during my Programming classes in Uni before and I'm curious as to what it means.

The only times I've had to implement it was:

1. When I had to create a `BackgroundWorker` that had to be added to the `ProgressChanged` event

   `Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => updatePing((int) e.UserState)));`
2. When researching tutorials on using the Caliburn.Micro MVVM framework

   `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Count);`

I have tried searching around on what this notation means but the special characters it uses seem to mess with google search and I have no idea what it is called.

Comment: It introduces a no-argument lambda expression (which is convertible to a no-argument `Action` or `Func<T>` delegate, depending on its content.) It's basically shorthand for creating an anonymous function (though it's actually more powerful than that.) Read about them here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Ah, there we go, see I didn't know it was called a lambda expression and searching `=>` wouldn't yield any results.

Comment: Searching for `"=>"` works OK.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `=>` is syntax for a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

The `()` signifies that there are no parameters - if there were parameters and the types could be inferred from context, they could be specified as something like this:

```
(x, y) => x + y
```

Or specifying the types explicitly

```
(int x, string y) => x + y.Length
```

If there's only *one* parameter and its type can be inferred, you don't need the brackets:

```
x => x.Length
```

Answer (score 10):

that's a lambda expression with no parameters.

What you're really doing, is passing a `delegate`(which is sorta like a variable for methods) into your function

---

`() => Count` represents a method resembling the following

```
type methodName()
{
    return Count;
}
```

Comment: You got skeet'd.

Comment: So what is the difference between `() => Count`, and just passing `Count`

Comment: @ChaoticLoki it matters if `Count` gets changed after you pass the delegate, but before you actually invoke it.  If you just pass `Count` than it will return what count was when you passed it.

Comment: It also lets you do more complicated logic. For example, if the method you're passing the lambda to is asynchronous, the lambda expression could represent an entire callback function, like this: `doSomeExpensiveAsyncMethod(x, y, () => dialog.TellUserThatOperationIsFinished())`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII  Funny thing is, It almost seems like Jon Skeet's very presence is pulling additional traffic into this question, causing my answer to be up-voted more than it would have been had he not posted here.